# Changing primary/accent/warn colors for Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Angular Material 2/Typescript to build an application. The default theme for these controls is not compatible with my company's colors, so I've been changing them. However, it'd be so much easier if I could change the root color for primary, accent, and warn, rather than having to override them using LESS throughout my application. Is there a way to easily do this without having to go into the node_modules folder?

Comment: until now there is no way: see https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/123

Comment: Probably solved by now but I just answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734518/changing-primary-color-in-angular-material-2. I uses sass but same diff as less...